# Doctrine ArrayCollection remove element not working

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Even if the object is correctly updated it seems that the data is not persisted and I don't get it why.

Here is my Entity:

> Article.php

```
/**
 * @var AttributeInArticle
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(
 *      targetEntity="XXX\DatabaseBundle\Entity\AttributeInArticle",
 *      mappedBy="article"
 * )
 */
private $attributeInArticles;

....

public function __construct()
{
    $this->attributeInArticles = new ArrayCollection();
}


/**
 * @return AttributeInArticle
 */
public function getAttributeInArticles()
{
    return $this->attributeInArticles;
}

public function addAttributeInArticle(AttributeInArticle $attributeInArticles)
{
    $this->attributeInArticles[] = $attributeInArticles;

    return $this;
}

public function removeAttributeInArticle(AttributeInArticle $attributeInArticles)
{
    $this->attributeInArticles->removeElement($attributeInArticles);
}
```

> AttributeInArticle.php

```
/**
 * @var  Attribute
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(
 *      targetEntity="XXX\DatabaseBundle\Entity\Attribute",
 *      inversedBy="attributeInArticles"
 * )
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(
 *          name="attribute_id",
 *          referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $attribute;

/**
 * @var Article
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(
 *      targetEntity="XXX\DatabaseBundle\Entity\Article",
 *      inversedBy="attributeInArticles"
 * )
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *       @ORM\JoinColumn(
 *          name="article_id",
 *          referencedColumnName="id"
 *      )
 * })
 *
 */
private $article;

/**
 * @return Attribute
 */
public function getAttribute()
{
    return $this->attribute;
}

/**
 * @param Attribute $attribute
 */
public function setAttribute($attribute)
{
    $this->attribute = $attribute;
}

+ getter & setter for $article
```

And in the controller I am calling it like this:

```
$article->removeAttributeInArticle($attributeInArticle);
```

If I dumpthe $article object before and after the remove action the $article object has the corect data in it. That means that $attributeInArticle was removed.

But for some reason it does not persist this data.

Comment: do you call persist() and flush() afterwards?

Comment: yes. i end up in removing the object itself... so for now it works but it is not working as a real ArrayCollection

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is easy here.

You are removing an `Attribute` from an `Article` and the persisting/flushing `Article`. If you look to your mappings you'll notice easily that the relationship between `Article` and `AttributeInArticole` is owned by the latter.

When you do flushing operations, doctrine, for performance reasons, "looks" only to owning side of a relationship and for changes in it: if nothing changed there's no need to write it in db.

So, what you can do here, is to remove the `$attributeInArticle` directly without worry about `Article` entity.

So, basically

```
$em = $this
    ->getDoctrine()
    ->getManager();

$em->remove($attributeInArticle);
$em->flush();
```

Another option is to use [`orphanRemoval`](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#orphan-removal) on `$attribueInArticles` of your `Article` entity.

So, basically,

```
//Article.php

/**
 * @var AttributeInArticle
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(
 *      targetEntity="XXX\DatabaseBundle\Entity\AttributeInArticle",
 *      mappedBy="article",
 *      orphanRemoval=true
 * )
 */
private $attributeInArticles;
```

and

```
$article->removeAttributeInArticle($attributeInArticle);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I did in the end :) I will accept this because of the extensive explanation why this is so and not different! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need `cascade={"remove"}`

```
/**
 * @var AttributeInArticle
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(
 *      targetEntity="XXX\DatabaseBundle\Entity\AttributeInArticle",
 *      mappedBy="article",
 *      cascade={"remove"}
 * )
 */
```

Read doctrine documentation: [8. Working with Associations](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html). Also check "Orphan Removal"